# Why does my Hand hurt when i play fast things on piano?

Tags: piano, technique, practice

So im am trying to prepare for my Examination and my hands hurt whenever im playing something fast or with a lot of notes. I tryied relaxing a little bit it doesn't help. Also i have to practice a lot becouse i am behind o some stuff so I cant just stop becouse my Hand hurts. Do you have some suggestions or something? I have no idea how to stop it from cramping so much.

Comment: You need to see a doctor, not ask random internet musicians. Cramps have too many indirect causes to be diagnosed by amateurs.

Comment: Do not continue to play when there is pain. It's too bad you're behind in your preparation, but you can do permanent damage to your hands if you try to play through pain.

Comment: Is it in both hands? Where specifically do you feel it? What piece(s) are you studying? How long do you play before the pain starts? Is there pain if you play the same passages at a slower tempo? As a pianist, there's too much information missing to suggest how to improve your technique.

Comment: I suggest rewriting the question along the following lines: "I tense up when I play measures X – Y of 'Name of Piece' by 'Composer'. The problem occurs in my 'LH/RH/LH+RH'." Also provide an image of the musical passage involved. By keeping the question focused specifically on piano technique in a specific passage, we might be able to offer technique suggestions. But since your pain is significant, consistent, and ongoing, you still need to see a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

> I tryied relaxing a little bit it doesn't help.

Try relaxing a LOT!   And generally checking out posture, seat height, arm/hand position...

And, if it hurts, take a break.  This isn't negotiable, no matter how behind you are.

Also, don't practice hard, practice smart.   There's no point in taking 10 runs at a passage and getting it wrong 9 times.   Go slower and get it right 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong muscles to play.  You need to find a new teacher, yours failed you. Without seeing you play I can't tell you what needs correcting but pretty much what it sounds like, well, two things:  You are probably using two muscles to move one bone in two directions and that is causing strain.  It is called a muscular co-contraction.  I'd say ask your teacher about it but . . .  The second thing is you could be pressing into the keybed which will strain your long flexor tendons.

Nine times out of ten it is the muscular co-contraction. If your teacher tells you you need exercises, to practice slow or to relax, run fast and far from that teacher.  Slow is good but if you don't correct what you are doing wrong slow practice only solidifies the improper movement.  If you relax, you'll fall to the floor or your hands won't work.  It is true you need to relax but, relax the wrong muscles and employ the correct ones.  Exercises are the same, if you practice wrong, more wrongful practice won't make it better.

You most likely already have improper movement hardwired into your brain's muscle memory and it is an arduous task to overwrite those movements.  If you find a teacher who knows what they are doing then you can never play your old repertoire for the improper movement is even hardwired into the songs.

Much luck to you.  It took me ten years to rewire my brain and I am still fighting improper movement always trying to reassert itself.